JavasScript Open Local File
I am writing a Figma plugin that uses JavaScript and I need to open a file from the plugin folder. This is not JS on a webpage. I mention that because all the JS examples I can find assume a <input type='file'/>.
The code should look something like this:
function readFile (file: File)
{
    let reader = new FileReader() ;
    reader.onload = () =>
    {
        console.log(reader.result) ;
    }
    reader.readAsText(file) ;
}

readFile(new File("folder/File.xml")) ;

At least, that is what I would expect from using other languages such as Java.
However, new File("folder/File.xml") does not compile. The parameters described in other sources seem to imply that you use new File() to create a file, not to read an existing file.
See, for example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File

The code should look something like this: what happens when the code does look like that?

Using the File constructor as shown in your example code would result in a TypeError. Can you [edit] the post to include a single, direct question? See [ask] for more info.

To read a file from the plugin folder in a Figma plugin, you will need to use the figma API to access files and read their contents. Here is an example of how you can achieve this:
async function readFile(filePath) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(filePath);
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        const fileContent = await response.text();
        console.log(fileContent);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error reading the file:', error);
    }
}

const filePath = './folder/File.xml';

readFile(filePath);


https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

This gives the error: {message: "Failed to construct 'Request': Failed to parse URL from ./folder/File.xml"}
It seems as if fetch expects to find a url, not a filename.
If I add 'file:' in front of the filename then I get the error: VM4710:6 Not allowed to load local resource
